# I need to calculate running total in Azure SQL Datawarehouse. Tried recursive CTEs but not supported

Tags: sql, azure, azure-synapse

Azure SQL Datawarehouse doesn't support recursive CTEs and I need a solution that works in Azure SQL DW for my problem.

I have table with my inventory details of various products. I have the quantities of products Produced, Sold and Returned per day. The initial quantity of the present day will be final quantity from previous day(I have it in other table, refer to Stocklevel table in image) and I have to calculate the final quantity for present day using Initial, Produced, Sold and Returned quantities of the day and the final quantity calculated of present day should be passed as an initial quantity for the next day for the same product and so on.

I tried using recursive CTEs and got error “Recursive common table expressions are not supported in this version.”

Please help if you have any other ideas. Thanks in Advance.

```
Final=Initial+Produced-Sold+Returned
```

In the image are the details I have.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

CTE is not supported in Synapse at this time and hence you got that message . I think we can play around with the Self join and achieve the ask here .

```
select a.productid, a.initial,a.produced,a.sold,a.Returned,a.Final,convert([date],a.date) as date 
,convert(date,DATEADD(dd,-1,a.Date))as yesterday, 
final =  isnull(a.initial,0) + a.produced + a.sold +a.Returned
from Inventary a 
JOIN Inventary B 
On A.Productid = b.Productid
and a.Date = DATEADD(dd,-1,b.Date)
group by a.productid, a.initial,a.produced,a.sold,a.Returned,a.Final,convert([date],a.date),convert(date,DATEADD(dd,-1,a.Date))
```